# Remove invalid contributor from GitHub

Tags: github

I accidentally committed with the wrong author (`Me <e@mail.com>`), because I'd used that as a placeholder author, to protect my privacy. On the GitHub page, the author appeared as [tCInUBkXfaMY](https://github.com/tCInUBkXfaMY), but they don't own the name `Me`.

To fix this, I amended the commit, backed up the master branch to another branch, then ran `git push --force`.

Even when deleting the backup branch, the contributor still appears on the project page.

The contributor appears nowhere on the graph (`graphs/contributors`), but still appears on the main page.

This only just happened, but I don't think it will fix itself - I saw the same thing happening on https://github.com/GandyT/GandyClient-2.0.

Comment: GitHub's "who made contributions" graph is updated infrequently. They use an "instant boost" method to count recently pushed contributions. Then, a day or week or month later, they re-calculate the *correct* number and forget the "boost" values. So eventually this will go back to where it should be.

Comment: The *list of contributors* probably never updates though. You'd have to ask GitHub about this: it's a GitHub thing, not a Git thing.

Comment: Still hasn't updated.

Comment: Okay, now it's updated! Didn't take long

Answer (score 0):

I successfully removed invalid contributors after contacting GitHub.

You can contact GitHub via the link: https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-remove-data

Mention your repo url in the content and say that you need to delete invalid contributors. They will help you clear these cached information manually.